# Array of submatrices to be multiplied by array of scalars

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

A is a 10 x 10 array of scalars, shape=(10,10)

B is a 10 x 10 array of 3 x 3 matrices, shape=(10,10,3,3)

There are 100 scalars in A and 100 3 x 3 matrices in B. I would like for each 3 x 3 matrix in B to be multiplied by a corresponding scalar in A.

I was able to do this with a simple function like this:

```
def C(i,j):
   return A[i,j]*B[i,j]
```

but I wondered if it could be done using even simpler numpy-compatible expressions (without a new function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add new axes to `A` and then multiply with `B` to get the desired result:

```
A[:, :, None, None] * B
```

This correctly aligns the axes so each scalar in `A` multiplies the corresponding 3x3 matrix in `B`.

A smaller example for demonstration:

```
>>> A = np.arange(1, 5).reshape(2, 2)
>>> B = np.ones((2, 2, 3, 3)
>>> A[:, :, None, None] * B
array([[[[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
         [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
         [ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

        [[ 2.,  2.,  2.],
         [ 2.,  2.,  2.],
         [ 2.,  2.,  2.]]],


       [[[ 3.,  3.,  3.],
         [ 3.,  3.,  3.],
         [ 3.,  3.,  3.]],

        [[ 4.,  4.,  4.],
         [ 4.,  4.,  4.],
         [ 4.,  4.,  4.]]]]
```

Comment: @omegamanda: glad it helped - if you feel your question has been answered, do consider marking the answer as accepted (or let me know if you'd like any further explanation).

Comment: actually i tried to do it immediately after my comment, but it kept telling me i needed to wait 2 minutes, so i forgot about it